# C code for analog read of SD24 ADC (MSP430I2041)

Tags: analog, c, msp430

I am trying to read the output of the ADC into an array by taking the output from the memory register but for some reason it is not working, the array values stay as 0:

```
   int adc[100] = {0}; //Sets up an array of 100 integers and zero's the values
   int i=0;

  // Function prototypes
  void adc_Setup();
  void adc_Sam();

  void main()
  {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;           // Stop WDT
    adc_Setup();                        
    while(i<100)
    {
      adc_Sam();    // activating the adc 100 times 
    }
  }

 // ADC set-up function
 void adc_Setup()
 {
   SD24CCTL0 = SD24OSR_1024+SD24SNGL+SD24IE;  // SINGLE CONVERSION ENA IONTURRPUT    
   SD24INCTL0 = SD24INCH_0;        // Select Channel A0, SD24INTDLYx = 00
                                   // SD24INCTL0 |= SD24GAINx FOR GAIN FROM 1 TO 16
 }

 // ADC sample conversion function
 void adc_Sam()
 {
   SD24CCTL0=SD24SC; // activates the adc this is a control register
   __delay_cycles(1000);
   while (SD24CCTL0  & BUSY)// waits
   {        
      __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);// Low Power Mode 0
   }
    adc[i]=SD24MEM0; // takes  the data from the output of the adc
    i++;
 }
```

---

Also this memory register holds only 16 bit out of the 24 bits. You can switch if you want it to hold the LSB or the MSB. So If I want all the bits. do I have to switch it and save the info twice, then take the missing 8 bits? Or is there a better way?

**update:**
There was no problem CCS Only display values of the variables that are declared in the main function that is all

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code because it is a mess.

Comment: I've not looked at all of the code, but what happens when `i` reaches 100?

Comment: @RogerRowland forgot the while loop condition

Comment: It wasn't me, but @Nick.

Comment: Perhaps setting the CPU into a low power mode shuts off the ADC.  If it were me, I would be reading the documentation about the low power mode(s).

Comment: suggest 'or'ing the bits of a register rather than '+'ing the bits.  Adding the bits can be a problem it one of the bits happens to be the sign bit (if used in a math operation).

Comment: assigning the bits to a register sets all the other bits in that register to 0, probably not a good idea.  Suggest using '|=' so other bits in the register are not changed.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to configure the reference voltage (the default is an external reference, which you did not mention).

Section 13.2.7.2 of the User's Guide says:

> When SD24LSBTOG = 1, the SD24LSBACC bit is automatically toggled each time the corresponding
>   channel's SD24MEMx register is read. This allows the complete digital filter output result to be read with
>   two read accesses of SD24MEMx.

Comment: so If In the setup I make the reference internal by adding SD24REFS=1; I should start seeing the arrat variable change?